# Is there a way to automatically kill a specific process if the CPU reaches the X temperature?

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I have a software that runs always when I'm out of home, but lately I noticed it could totally burn off my CPU if something goes wrong, so I need a code to put in a bat file that will kill the process if the CPU will reach the X temperature (in example, over 70°).

Comment: **I need a code**, is not what we do here. Please take the [tour] and read [ask], and you should get a better understanding.

Comment: It's better to invest into a proper cooling system than killing processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done it in PowerShell Script.
For those who may need it in the future, it goes in loop and check high CPU usage.

```
function CheckCPU {
$CPU = (gwmi Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process | ? {$_.Name -like 
'paint'}).PercentProcessorTime
}    

function CheckProcess {
if($CPU -ge 70)
{
Get-Process -Name paint| Stop-Process 
}
Else
{
echo "-------------------------------------------------------------------"
Get-Date -Format g
echo "All Ok: Usage of paint is $CPU % of CPU - Re-check in next 10 seconds."
echo "-------------------------------------------------------------------"
Start-Sleep -s 10
Scriptinzi
}
}

function Scriptinzi {
CheckCPU
CheckProcess }

Scriptinzi
```

Comment: This is not exactly what you asked in your question? You mentioned cpu temperature, but this script checks CPU utilization?

Comment: In these days of muli-processor computing, it is also less common for a single process to utilise `70%` of your processing power too as they tend not to process their instructions across all of the available cores.